# Unable to delete a file in Java - Cannot figure out what I am missing

Tags: java

I tried this code outside of my application and it works great, but I cannot for the life of me figure out why this will not delete the inputFile and rename the tempFile.

```
    private void jButton3MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
File inputFile = new File("c:\\test.csv");
File tempFile = new File("c:\\temp.csv");
    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

        String lineToRemove = tf_custID.getText() + "," + tf_custName.getText() + "," + tf_contactName.getText() + "," + tf_lastContact.getText() + "," + tf_phoneNumber.getText() + "," + tf_shippingAddress.getText() + "," + tf_shippingAddress2.getText() + "," + tf_City.getText() + "," + cb_State.getSelectedItem().toString() + "," + tf_Zipcode.getText() + ","; 
        String currentLine;

        while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            // trim newline when comparing with lineToRemove
            String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
            //System.err.println(trimmedLine);
            //System.err.println(lineToRemove);
            if(trimmedLine.equals(lineToRemove)) continue;
            writer.write(currentLine);
            writer.write("\n");                
        }


        reader.close();            
        writer.close();

        } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    if(inputFile.delete())
    {
        System.out.println("** Input File Deleted Successfully, renaming temporary file. **");
        boolean successful = tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
        if(successful)
        {
            System.out.println("** Temporary File Renamed Successfully");
        }
        else
        {
            System.err.println("** Temporary File Rename Failed");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.err.println("** Unable to Delete Input File **");            
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance, I am just stuck.

Comment: So does it work or not?  If your SSCCE works then the problem is most likely in whatever you took out.

Comment: What, if anything, is printed out in the console (std err)?

Comment: No sysout/err result provided, no understanding possible.

Comment: No, it does not work inside the application. Thing is, I took this entire block of code outside of the application, I run it and works fine, deletes the inputFile and renames the tempFile, put it back into the application and it stops working, cannot delete file triggers. The only thing different is the event declaration and what it is searching for. The program copies the proper information to the temp file, the only thing that stops is the actual deleting of the inputFile.

Comment: Understood, there is nothing being caught in the exceptions. The only thing printing out to the console is "** Unable to Delete Input File **, not catching anything in the exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before you delete you should make sure your file exists so you can better report on the problem.  **I don't see you calling `inputFile.createNewFile();`** and I beleive if the delete is returning false there may be a couple possible reasons but most likely it's because the files doesn't exists so try...

```
if (inputFile.exists()){
   doDelete(inputFile); //<-- your delete code.
}else{
   System.out.println(String.format("Oops I thought the file [%s] existed", inputFile));
}
```

**ALSO**...

I would check out [Commons-IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) to help with the boilerplate code that is needed for file IO in java.  It's a nice library for this kind of stuff.

Comment: Actually, Michael's post actually got me thinking. In the search for the account that determines what to delete. I opened BufferedReader and never closed it when the search completes so it actually had a second reader open and I did not even realize it. So while his comment was not the direct answer, it allowed me to take a look deeper into the code. I knew it had to be something ridiculous I was overlooking. Thanks for all the answers!